# Transform array into tree Object

Tags: arrays, angular, csv, transform

I want to create a little tool that visualises an amount of data that is given through a CSV file and return it as a tree Object.

The CSV file will always contain the same columns: "Level 1", "Level 2", "Level 3"

What I have managed to do is to get the CSV data as an Object:

```
[
{
    "Level 1": "Cluster A",
    "Level 2": "Domain L",
    "Level 3": "Product R"
},
{
    "Level 1": "Cluster A",
    "Level 2": "Domain L",
    "Level 3": "Product S"
},
{
    "Level 1": "Cluster A",
    "Level 2": "Domain M",
    "Level 3": "Product T"
},
{
    "Level 1": "Cluster A",
    "Level 2": "Domain M",
    "Level 3": "Product U"
},
{
    "Level 1": "Cluster B",
    "Level 2": "Domain N",
    "Level 3": "Product V"
},
{
    "Level 1": "Cluster B",
    "Level 2": "Domain N",
    "Level 3": "Product W"
},
{
    "Level 1": "Cluster B",
    "Level 2": "Domain O",
    "Level 3": "Product Y"
}
]
```

What I want it to become is the following:

```
[
    {
        "Domain L": [
            {
                "Cluster A": [
                    {
                       "Product R"
                    },
                    {
                       "Product S"
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Domain M": [
            {
                "Cluster A": [
                    {
                       "Product T"
                    },
                    {
                       "Product U"
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                "Cluster B": [
                    {
                       "Product V"
                    },
                    {
                       "Product W"
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

I'm working in Angular and I am trying to adapt it inside the logic Type/JavaScript, but I don't seem to get it correct in any ways. Could Somebody help me on the way with this?

Comment: The elements of an array should be the same "fields" (else you early get in troubles). NOTE: Generally you create an empty array, loop over the array and in loop check conditions to add a new element or change an element existing. You can loop the array using forEach or reduce or a simple for.